# Adding multiple edit texts to an alert dialog

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I've implemented an alert dialog containing one edit text for `name` but I need to store other info such a `quantity` `location` using the same alert dialog.

I tried to add another edit text by simply declaring another but this didn't populate the dialog with another edit text.

Does anyone now how you can add extra edit text object to an alert dialog?

This is how I've implemented an alert dialog for containing one edit text:

```
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            alert.setTitle("Generic Info");
            alert.setMessage("Ship Name");

            // Set an EditText view to get user input 
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            alert.setView(input);

            //need to add two more edit text fields for extra input.


            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
              Editable value = input.getText();
              // Do something with value!

              }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // Canceled.
              }
            });

            alert.show();
            return true;
```

Comment: Similar question has already been asked more than once, please search before posting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Create res/layout/custom_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Text 1"
        android:id="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Text 2"
        android:id="@+id/editText2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Text 3"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Text 4"
        android:id="@+id/editText4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your Activity that you want AlertDialog to show use:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setTitle("Custom view with 4 EditTexts");
        builder.setMessage("AlertDialog");
        builder.setView(R.layout.custom_view);
        //In case it gives you an error for setView(View) try
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null));
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
        return builder.create();
```

And this will give you the following result:

[image]

Comment: I tried the above but I get error `The method setView(View) in the type AlertDialog.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (int)` at this line `builder.setView(R.layout.custom_view);` I'm not sure why it says `int` as my custom_view is xml file not int.

Comment: I run app on my project and the screenshot is from my App.. So post your code to see what is going on!!!

Comment: Check my answer..I editted it

Comment: I saw what was going on. Now it should be fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68134/discussion-between-kostasmatrix-and-brian-j).

Comment: One question - shouldn't you call create() before show() and not the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Relative Layout

add as many edittext as you want

and then set relative layout in  `alert.setView(relativeLayout);`

can not write whole code for you 
but see here [custom layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout)   , this will surely help you .

Comment: Can you show me a code example of this approach?